# Offline Mapping API

Tags: .net, dictionary, mapping

Are there any services available that allow me to manipulate maps in an offline setting? I am working on a project that requires me to take a map and based on features on the map, generate a game world. I have looked at a few of the API's for different providers: Google, ms, etc. The API's I looked seem to be strictly showing a user a map. I am looking for something that allows me to create a derivative of a map (the Gameworld), that will never be seen by the public, and is only used by the game engine. However one caveat is that I would like to be able to link the derivative created for use by the game engine, with something I can show the user.

As an example. Think of a cross country racing sim. Users cannot control the vehicles directly in this game, they can only control the cars setup, driver, etc. I create a gameworld from a map. The gameworld data (driver position, etc) is overlayed onto a real map. A race might last several days. The only interaction users have with the real map is viewing their position on the map, and where they are in relation to the others.

I don't want to violate the terms of the API here. I read Googles API TOS, and it seems to me that creating the gameworld would violdate their TOS.

The features I really need are the following

- The ability to locate a specific
  place on the map by lat/long
- The ability/rights to grab those maps
  and save them as an image file
  temporarily for processing
- The ability/rights to store a
  gameworld that is based on the real
  map
- The ability to show a user a map with
  an overlay (this is optional. I can use googles API, or any other one that supports lat/long.)

Edit:
The gameworld creation will only happen once intially, and partial updates may occur very infrequently. I will only need to generate the world in the beginning.
This is also for a free game, so I am looking for something opensource

Edit:
I only need maps of the US. I need maps that contain rivers and lakes.

Comment: have you looked at ESRI?

Comment: @Maud'Dib It looks like it would be a good solution. However, the game I am developing is free. I am not really wanting to spend 1500 up front to develop on their platform.

Comment: I may just need to run my own mapping server such as Geoserver, and find some free GIS data that I can use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I was looking for, actually I found something that should work.
ITs GMap.net a program written in C#. The offline stuff it does is perfect, and it even allows you to connect to map servers other than google.

http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/releases/view/20235

Answer (score 0):

Why not try out openmaps http://openmaps.eu/  You should be able to download their maps locally which means total offline use.

Comment: This won't work. the maps are not detailed enough it its features for use. (missing bodies of water)

Comment: actually I was thinking of a different site. This site didnt seem to have any maps in the US.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.openstreetmap.org/ ?

(Also, if you have specific requirements, eg. for maps of certain places, or for certain types of data such as altitude or whatever, it might be an idea to edit your original question.)

Comment: That was my fault. I looked at openstreemanp.org, and the problem with it is that it is missing river and lake information.